# Picklist value on record UI and label are different

Tags: picklist

I am observing that an existing custom field (lets call it 'Type'). I see that on the record page that the value I selected (and can change to other similar values) is of 'PR - A':

[image: Value from record detail page]

But the value in picklist configuration is PR|A (label and API both):

[image: Value from salesforce inspector extension]

What could be the reason behind this (considering this is a restricted picklist)?
The global picklist value on which it is derived from also has the same API/Label (PR|A) and not what I see on record page.

Answer (score 0):

This was a silly confusion.

Somebody had created 'Translations' using translation workbench only for English and it was showing different values on the UI as exepected.